# Unicode normalization for filenames and copied text from pdf:s

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

I have two issues that seem related. When copying text or filenames containing umlauts or e.g. å ä ö, OS X can't seem to handle the characters in a sane way. Apparently this is a well-known problem. For example:

- http://support.wandisco.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/401/55/problems-with-umlauts--in-filenames-on-mac-os-x
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94418/os-x-umlauts-in-utf8-nfd-yield-package-inputenc-error-unicode-char-u8-not

Here is an example of the usual result when copying text from a filename or from inside a pdf in Preview and pasting it in an editor. The first line is the result, the other one is corrected.

[image: example of copy]

The difference is clearly visible, since the current font (Courier Prime) doesn't support the first version.

Is there any way to fix this? Alternatively, is there any OS X-service available to "clean up" text or normalize it in the correct way?

Comment: I don't understand what normalization has to do with your problem, which looks like a font substitution issue.

Comment: PS  The reason for font substitution may be that Courier Prime is a somewhat limited font and lacks combining diacritical marks.  The copy I downloaded does not seem to have any.  That would mean it cannot handle any decomposed accented characters and normalization form C is required.  I think the best fix may be to use a more complete Unicode font instead.  They all normally include combining diacritics as far as I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HFS+ requires filenames to be in decomposed form (LATIN SMALL LETTER A + COMBINING DIAERESIS) instead of composed form (LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS). You can use iconv to convert text to composed form:

```
$ echo -n ä | xxd -p
c3a4
$ touch ä
$ ls | tr -d '\n' | xxd -p
61cc88
$ ls | tr -d '\n' | iconv -f utf-8-mac -t utf-8 | xxd -p
c3a4
```

[image]

HFS+ does not use NFD (normal form decomposed). From http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1173/_index.html:

> Important: The terms used in this Q&A, precomposed and decomposed, roughly correspond to Unicode Normal Forms C and D, respectively. However, most volume formats do not follow the exact specification for these normal forms. For example, HFS Plus (Mac OS Extended) uses a variant of Normal Form D in which U+2000 through U+2FFF, U+F900 through U+FAFF, and U+2F800 through U+2FAFF are not decomposed (this avoids problems with round trip conversions from old Mac text encodings).

Something like this might also work:

`python -c 'import unicodedata as ud; print ud.normalize("NFC", u"\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A}\N{COMBINING DIAERESIS}")'`